# Using HostGators preview feature, but my resources are being called without the full base_url in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel, shared-hosting

I'm using HostGators preview feature which allows you to preview your files on the server without having to point a url.

The formatting is like so

```
http://server.domain.com/~cpanelusername/
```

Now, I have my base_url set to the above in my config.php file, however I'm running into this issue. My resources are not going to the url as listed above, but instead is trying to load them like:

```
http://server.domain.com/resources/images/logo.png
```

As you can see it's doing it without the CPanel Username in the url.

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://server.domain.com/~q0j8t5p6/";
```

This is what my base_url looks like in the file.

Has anybody successfully made this work? If so, how?

Comment: do you call your resources with `base_url()` ? eg: `base_url('resources/images/logo.png')` ?

Comment: My stylesheet is being called like:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo     base_url('resources/css/app.css')?>">`

Comment: This is one of the reasons I never mess around with the preview URL.  Just buy a cheap domain name you can use for temporary testing.  Otherwise, add a temporary subdomain to your primary domain and use that instead.

Comment: Check your `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` CodeIgniter setting to see if the cPanel username contains disallowed characters.